# installing JCE Editor

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Hi everyone I intall JCE Editor for joomla2.5

I have the component active and everything is fine and don´t show any error when I install
But when I create a new article o whatever I can insert html or php code in my article or custom module.

Any idea or suggest!

Comment: Please provide more information. What have you tried, what do you expected and what is the problem in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Control Panel->Global Configuration

Select your Default Editor as "Editor JCE Editor".

Then Click Save Button